# Adding Two Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had a problem in Python. I was trying to make an addition calculator but a problem popped up. My code is attached.

```
prompt = input("Do you want to use this calculator? Y for yes and N for no ")
if prompt == 'n' :
    print ("Maybe next time. ")
if prompt == 'y':
    numberone = input("What is your first number? ")
    numbertwo = input("What is your second number? ")
    print ("Your equation is ",numberone, "+ ",numbertwo, )
    answer = (numberone * numbertwo)
    print ("Your answer is ",answer, )
```

When I print the answer it comes out as two numbers combined. For example if I'm using 9+10, it'll come out as 910. I don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: If it worked for you, you can select it as an answer by clicking the checkmark. As for where to learn python, [their docs are a good place to start](https://www.python.org/doc/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` gets the input from the user and returns it as a string.

You need to convert the `input` to a number. I presume you want the numbers to be `int`, but you could just replace `int` with `float` if you need to.

```
prompt = input("Do you want to use this calculator? Y for yes and N for no ")
if prompt == 'n' :
    print ("Maybe next time. ")
elif prompt == 'y':
    numberone = int(input("What is your first number? "))
    numbertwo = int(input("What is your second number? "))
    print ("Your equation is ",numberone, "+ ",numbertwo, )
    answer = (numberone + numbertwo)
    print ("Your answer is ",answer, )
```

Comment: As an aside, `n+m` isn't an *equation*, it's an *expression*. :)

Comment: Thank you I will change it.

Comment: Another aside, your code is multiplying the two numbers, not adding them.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that for me.

Comment: @erip -- Not the downvoter, but side note: in Python 2, `input` will evaluate what you enter so you don't need to convert it to an `int`; however, it is literally the same as `eval(raw_input(...))`, which is why to read a `str` you use `raw_input`, else you'll likely get a `NameError`. This is *not true* in Python 3, where `input` has the same behavior as `raw_input` (and `raw_input` does not exist). Perhaps the tag above needs to be changed to `python-3.x`.